# Cancel drag or disable reorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Is there a way to cancel drop action of react-beautiful-dnd's Draggable object? I have a list of items with one item to be always at last position. [image]

I want to disable (or at least properly cancel) drop if item is dragged below last item. I know I can exclude last item from droppable component and area, but that's not an option.

Comment: Component `Draggable` has attribute named `isDragDisabled`. Try to set it on `true`.

Comment: I've already tried to bind this property to parent component state and change it in 'onDragUpdate'. As soon as I change component's state, I receive 'Error: Invariant failed: Should not recreate scheduler while capturing'

Comment: Try setting `isDragDisabled` `onBeforeCapture` rather then `onDragUpdate` this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple

When you drop any element in the `onDragEnd` method you'll get an object for `destination and source` so in that `destination` you find one `index`.

This `index` is referred to as your element at that index in your list of elements.

So you can make one condition there like if your element list length is equal to your index then don't do nothing `return` from that function.